# Extract filename from path

Tags: vba, wildcard

I need to extract the filename from a path (a string):

e.g.,
**"C:\folder\folder\folder\file.txt" = "file"** (or even "file.txt" to get me started)

Essentially everything before and including the last \

I've heard of using wildcards in place of Regex (as it's an odd implementation in VBA?) but can't find anything solid.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: using which programming language?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it. My answer includes Java code.

Comment: You might do well to have a look at the VBA help for the 'FileSystemObject`, and its 'GetFileName` method...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [kaveman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453168/kaveman) for the help. Here is the full code I used to remove both the path and the extension (it is not full proof, does not  take into consideration files that contain more than 2 decimals eg. *.tar.gz)

```
sFullPath = "C:\dir\dir\dir\file.txt"   
sFullFilename = Right(sFullPath, Len(sFullPath) - InStrRev(sFullPath, "\"))
sFilename = Left(sFullFilename, (InStr(sFullFilename, ".") - 1))
```

sFilename = "file"

Comment: To only remove the last extension (in filenames with more than one dot), use InStrRev -- i.e. change you last line to `sfilename = Left(sFullFilename, (InStrRev(sFullFilename, ".") - 1))`

Answer (score 26):

I believe this works, using VBA:

```
Dim strPath As String
strPath = "C:\folder\folder\folder\file.txt"

Dim strFile As String
strFile = Right(strPath, Len(strPath) - InStrRev(strPath, "\"))
```

`InStrRev` looks for the first instance of "\" from the end, and returns the position. `Right` makes a substring starting *from the right* of given length, so you calculate the needed length using `Len - InStrRev`

Comment: sorry I had to edit that: you need to use `Len(..) - InStrRev(..)` to get the difference in length from the whole string and the position of the last "\", which is the length of the substring you would like to take from the right. I tried this in Excel2007 and it gave me "file.txt"

Comment: I added an extension of your solution that solves my exact scenario. Thanks for the help bud!

Comment: See my comment below on Matt Rowles's answer.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for a solution without code. This VBA works in the Excel Formula Bar:

To extract the file name:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","~",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","")))))
```

To extract the file path:

```
=MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)-LEN(MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))+1,LEN(A1))))
```

Comment: You might substitute ~ for any special character, if your file has ~ in it.

Answer (score 2):

`You can also try:

`Sub filen()
    Dim parts() As String
    Dim Inputfolder As String, a As String
        'Takes input as any file on disk
        Inputfolder = Application.GetOpenFilename("Folder, *")
        parts = Split(Inputfolder, "\")
        a = parts(UBound(parts()))
    MsgBox ("File is: " & a)
End Sub`

This sub can display Folder name of any file

Answer (score 2):

Here's simpler method: a **one-line function** to extract *only* the name — without the file extension — as you specified in [your example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5932909/8112776):

```
Function getName(pf):getName=Split(Mid(pf,InStrRev(pf,"\")+1),".")(0):End Function
```

...so, using your example, this:

`MsgBox getName("C:\folder\folder\folder\file.txt")`

returns:

[image: "file"]

For cases where you want to extract the filename while **retaining the file extension**, or if you want to **extract the only the path**, here are two more **single-line functions**:

> ### Extract Filename from `x:\path\filename`:
>
> ```
> Function getFName(pf)As String:getFName=Mid(pf,InStrRev(pf,"\")+1):End Function
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ### Extract Path from `x:\path\filename`:
>
> ```
> Function getPath(pf)As String: getPath=Left(pf,InStrRev(pf,"\")): End Function
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **Examples:**
>   [image: examples]

<sup>([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50014189/8112776))</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using Java:

```
String myPath="C:\folder\folder\folder\file.txt";
System.out.println("filename " +  myPath.lastIndexOf('\\'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I used kaveman's suggestion successfully as well to get the Full File name but sometimes when i have lots of Dots in my Full File Name, I used the following to get rid of the .txt bit:

```
FileName = Left(FullFileName, (InStrRev(FullFileName, ".") - 1))
```

Comment: It was intended as a thanks and an alternative answer. It was my very first time here, so sorry if I did something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a FileSystemObject for that.

First, include a reference for de **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** (*VB Editor Menu Bar > Tools > References*).

After that, you can use a function such as this one:

```
Function Get_FileName_fromPath(myPath as string) as string
    Dim FSO as New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    'Check if File Exists before getting the name
    iF FSO.FileExists(myPath) then
        Get_FileName_fromPath = FSO.GetFileName(myPath)
    Else
        Get_FileName_fromPath = "File not found!"
    End if
End Function
```

*File System Objects* are very useful for file manipulation, especially when checking for their existence and moving them around. I like to use them early bound (Dim statement), but you can use them late bound if you prefer (CreateObject statement).

Answer (score 0):

'[/vba]
' Keep It Simple
'            .. why use FileSystemObject or Split when Left and Mid will do  it
'    the FSO has some 33 Subs or Functions
that have to be loaded each time it is created.
'  and needs the file to exist  ... yet is only a bit slower

... under twice time.. some good code in FSO
'   conservation is good  .. spare a few electrons.  ????... save a few millionths of a sec

'Also
'            .. why the format of a function that we all seem to use like
'
'            .. Function GetAStr(x) as string

'            dim extraStr as string

'    a lot of work with extraStr..
'    that could have been done with the string variable GetAStr
already created by the function

'        then     ..  GetAStr=extraStr to put it in its right place
'            ..  End Function

Function GetNameL1$(FilePath$, Optional NLess& = 1)

' default  Nless=1 => name only
'  NLess =2 => xcopya.xls xcopyb.xls  xcopy7.xlsm all as xcopy to get find latest version
'  Nless = - 4 or less => name with name.ext  worka.xlsm

GetNameL1 = Mid(FilePath, InStrRev(FilePath, "") + 1)

GetNameL1 = Left(GetNameL1, InStrRev(GetNameL1, ".") - NLess)

End Function

Function LastFold$(FilePath$)

LastFold = Left(FilePath, InStrRev(FilePath, "") - 1)

LastFold = Mid(LastFold, InStrRev(LastFold, "") + 1)

End Function

Function LastFoldSA$(FilePath$)

Dim SA$(): SA = Split(FilePath, "")

LastFoldSA = SA(UBound(SA) - 1)

End Function

[<vba]