# Function to extract remaining string after last backslash

Tags: excel, vba, replace, excel-formula, find-replace

I need an Excel function that can extract a string after last `\` from a path and if no `\` found then take the whole string. For example:

```
D:\testing\rbc.xls                     output will be   rbc.xls
D:\home\testing\test1\script1.sql      output will be   script.sql
script 3.txt                           output will be   script 3.txt
```

Comment: welcome at stackoverflow. please note that this isn't a free code-writing service. please share what have you tried so far and where do you get stuck.

Comment: Have you looked at function `InStrRev` which finds the last occurence of a substring in a main string.  `Pos = InStrRev(PathFileName,"\")` gives the last "\". `FileName = Mis$(PathFileName,Pos+1)` extracts the characters after the slash.

Comment: I suggest you read down the alphabetic lists of VBA functions and methods. In my early days I did this every month or so until, when I came to a new problem, I knew there was a function that did what I needed even if I did not remember the syntax.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site does not exist to duplicate the documentation provided with programming languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract filename from path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932909/extract-filename-from-path)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1.Change all the "\" to spaces, the number of spaces is determined by the number of characters in the cell

2.Use the right function to extract the right of the string based on the number of characters in the cell.

3.Use the trim function to remove the spaces.

[image]

Your results will be.

[image]

`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))`

As suggested, one way to do this without formulas or vba would be to use "Find/Replace".
Hit Ctrl & "H" keys and do the following.

Find what *\  and replace with nothing

[image]

The VBA code for that would be

```
Sub ReplaceIt()
    Columns("A").Replace What:="*\", Replacement:="", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Two other techniques added