# How to get workbook filename of opened XML file?

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I tried looking this over the Internet (also on SO) but did not find any solution.

I am looking for a way to get a filename of opened XML. My code opens like this:

```
Workbooks.OpenXML FileName:=pliczek, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList
```

Variable `pliczek` is path of file and when code is executed new file is opened for example `Sheet1`. I want to know filename - I want to execute some code on it but no idea how to get this name.

Trying to activate next windows is risky if someone has more excel files opened.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743328/how-to-extract-file-name-from-path

Comment: Open() returns a reference to the workbook, so just assign that to a variable....

Comment: @KarolMarianSłuszniak there is no anwser to my question there.

Comment: @TimWilliams, `Open()` is not the same as `OpenXML`, especially when it goes with parameter `LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList`. As I wrote in my question, variable is path on HDD, so it's like `C:\1.xml`. When I open it with OpenXML it appears as `Sheet1` or other number at the end. I want to know programatically what name was given to a workbook so I reference to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:="C:\_Stuff\Test.xml", _
                               loadoption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)

    Debug.Print wb.Name, wb.Sheets(1).Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Easiest awnsers comes as the last :) Works as it should, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Code:

`ActiveWorkbook.Name` or if you need the full path `ActiveWorkbook.Path`