# Excel Vba - Pull File Name from File Path

Tags: excel, filenames, vba

My code below is used to select a file and load the file path into the textbox. I am trying to extract just the file name from this and put that in the textbox. I am sure there is a simple way to do this, but I cannot find out how. Thank you for any help!

```
Private Sub openDialog1()
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd

  .AllowMultiSelect = False

  .Title = "Please select the report."

  .Filters.Clear
  .Filters.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xls"
  .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

  If .Show = True Then
    TextBox1 = .SelectedItems(1)

  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract file name from path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743328/how-to-extract-file-name-from-path)

Comment: Somehow did not find this in my searching, I'll see if I can work it out from this.

Comment: Cool, give it a try (I'd suggest using the `FileSystemObject` method in the second answer).

Comment: I got it to work with the FileSystemObjectMethod, but do I need to select the Tools> references >Microsoft Scripting Runtime feature on every computer I run this code on? If that is so then I cannot use it.

Comment: No, you only need to load Microsoft Scripting Runtime feature to the workbook with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to discard the path part.  This will display the *filename.ext*

```
Sub openDialog1()
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd

  .AllowMultiSelect = False

  .Title = "Please select the report."

  .Filters.Clear
  .Filters.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xls"
  .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

  If .Show = True Then
    ary = Split(.SelectedItems(1), "\")
    MsgBox ary(UBound(ary))
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your solution was effective and much less complicated than the 'FileSystemObject' method. Thank you.