# Excel VBA: How to extract the substring if we know the positions of first and last letter in string

Tags: string, excel, vba

how can we extract a substring from a string if we give the positions of first and last letter in string?

```
Dim my_string As String
Dim my_substring As String
my_string="Excel/Sheet1.xls"
```

`instrrev(my_string,"/")` gives 6 (start position)

`len(my_string)` gives 16 (end position)

So to get "Sheet1.xls" as my substring what should we do?

Or we can get it selecting characters till "/" is met first/

Comment: use mid function. reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I don't think you'll do any better than the answers provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1755577/2071807)

Comment: LondonRob. Yes . Similar. But this deals with start and end positions of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mid(my_string,instrrev(my_string,"/")+1, len(my_string))
```

would give you `Sheet1.xls`.

Comment: Neat solution. I didn't know about `InStrRev`. I just learned something new. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

How about this one?

```
my_substring = Split("Excel/Sheet1.xls","/")(1)
```

Comment: This won't do what you expect it to do if there is more than one `/` in the string. Why not change it a bit to store the `Split` in a `Variant`, then get the *last* element with `UBound`?

Comment: May I suggest this slight improvement: `Split(strFileName, "/")(UBound(Split(strFileName, "/")))`

Comment: Ralph, in that case I would consider putting the array in a variant variable so that the split function does not have to execute twice. But it is true that my suggestion would not work with more than one /. It is even advisable to check if there are any....

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution:

```
Dim strFileName As String
strFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
Debug.Print "Start Position: " & Len(strFileName) - InStr(1, StrReverse(strFileName), "/")
Debug.Print "Extacted file name: " & Mid(strFileName, Len(strFileName) - InStr(1, StrReverse(strFileName), "/") + 2)
```