# Excel VBA: Macro to pull data from files in the folder with skipping already processed ones

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I adjusted the code I found on the Internet to pull data from the files in the folder and put them in one master sheet.

However, the numer of files will grow very quickly every week, so for that reason I would like to implement in the code that macro will skip the files that were already processed. I would like to do it by the looking up the file name in the master sheet (column U).

Please find the code below:

```
Option Explicit


Const FOLDER_PATH = "Z:\...\...\...\"  'REMEMBER END BACKSLASH


Sub ImportWorksheets()
   '=============================================
   'Process all Excel files in specified folder
   '=============================================
   Dim sFile As String           'file to process
   Dim fName As String
   Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
   Dim wbSource As Workbook
   Dim wsSource As Worksheet
   Dim rowTarget As Long         'output row
   Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
   Dim NR As Long
   rowTarget = 3

   'Setup
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro execution
    Application.EnableEvents = False    'turn off other macros for now
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'turn off system messages for now

    Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1")    'sheet report is built into

With wsMaster
    If MsgBox("Clear the old data first?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(3).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(4).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(5).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(6).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(7).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(8).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(9).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(10).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(11).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(12).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(13).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(14).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(15).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(17).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(18).Clear
        .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(20).Clear
        NR = 3

    Else
        NR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1    'appends data to existing data
    End If

   'check the folder exists
   If Not FileFolderExists(FOLDER_PATH) Then
      MsgBox "Specified folder does not exist, exiting!"
      Exit Sub
   End If

   'reset application settings in event of error
   On Error GoTo errHandler
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'set up the target worksheet
   Set wsTarget = Sheets("Arkusz1")

   'loop through the Excel files in the folder
   sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "*.xls*")
   Do Until sFile = ""

      'open the source file and set the source worksheet - ASSUMED WORKSHEET(1)
      Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & sFile)
      Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(3) 'EDIT IF NECESSARY

      'import the data
      With wsTarget
         .Range("C" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("F4").Value
         .Range("D" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J4").Value
         .Range("E" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J7").Value
         .Range("F" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J10").Value
         .Range("G" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J19").Value
         .Range("H" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("L19").Value
         .Range("I" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("H17").Value
         .Range("J" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("N27").Value
         .Range("K" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("N29").Value
         .Range("L" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("N36").Value
         .Range("M" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("N38").Value
         .Range("N" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J50").Value
         .Range("O" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("L50").Value
         .Range("Q" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J52").Value
         .Range("R" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("L52").Value
         .Range("T" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("N57").Value

         'optional source filename in the last column
         .Range("U" & rowTarget).Value = sFile
      End With

      'close the source workbook, increment the output row and get the next file
      wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
      rowTarget = rowTarget + 1
      sFile = Dir()
   Loop
   End If

   'Format columns to the desired format
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(7).NumberFormat = "### ### ##0"
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(8).NumberFormat = "### ### ##0"
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(9).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(10).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(11).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(12).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(13).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 $"
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(14).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(15).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(16).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(17).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(18).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(19).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
   .UsedRange.Offset(2).Columns(20).NumberFormat = "0.00%"

errHandler:
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   'tidy up
   Set wsSource = Nothing
   Set wbSource = Nothing
   Set wsTarget = Nothing
End With
End Sub




Private Function FileFolderExists(strPath As String) As Boolean
    If Not Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
End Function
```

I tried to make it by If and GoTo statement but I have very little knowledge in VBA and I have no idea how to actually formulate it skip files which names are already in master sheet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume for the moment that the file name in column `U` is the entire path with file extension.  i.e. `C:\Users\SL\Desktop\TestFile.xls`

You can use the `Find` method to look for any entries in column `U` that match `sFile` at the start of each loop.  If a match is found, skip over the file and move on, otherwise process it. Make sure you place `sFile = Dir()` outside the `If` statement to avoid an infinite loop.

```
Dim PathMatch As Range

'loop through the Excel files in the folder
sFile = Dir(FOLDER_PATH & "*.xls*")

Do Until sFile = ""
    With wsMaster.Range("U:U")
        Set PathMatch = .Find(What:=sFile, _
                                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                    MatchCase:=False)
    End With

    If Not PathMatch Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "File already processed, skip to next file."
    Else
        Debug.Print "File not processed yet, do it now"

        'open the source file and set the source worksheet - ASSUMED WORKSHEET(1)
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & sFile)
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(3) 'EDIT IF NECESSARY

        'import the data
        With wsTarget
           .Range("C" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("F4").Value
           .Range("D" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J4").Value
           .Range("E" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J7").Value
           .Range("F" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J10").Value
           .Range("G" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J19").Value
           .Range("H" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("L19").Value
           .Range("I" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("H17").Value
           .Range("J" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("N27").Value
           .Range("K" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("N29").Value
           .Range("L" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("N36").Value
           .Range("M" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("N38").Value
           .Range("N" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J50").Value
           .Range("O" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("L50").Value
           .Range("Q" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("J52").Value
           .Range("R" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("L52").Value
           .Range("T" & rowTarget).Value = wsSource.Range("N57").Value

           'optional source filename in the last column
           .Range("U" & rowTarget).Value = sFile
        End With

        'close the source workbook, increment the output row and get the next file
        wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
        rowTarget = rowTarget + 1
    End If
    sFile = Dir()
Loop
```

---

If you only have the file name and not the path you'll need to parse `sFile` accordingly.  [Here are a few ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1755577/2521004) to do that.