# how to get the filename of a file opened through Get Open FileName Application Command

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the filename of the Excel file that is opened, however keep getting the full path plus the filename. For example, I keep getting: C:\some_dir\other_dir\another_dir\filename.xls  when in reality, I just want filename out of filename.xls.  The issue is that the user could go into many sub-directories so can't simply use a parsor since it may change every time. Thoughts?

```
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFileName(Title:="Select File to Open")
```

Comment: Apart from Tim's methods, if you are going to open the file selected, then you can use something like `set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFileToOpen)` to open the file, followed by `filename = wb.Name` to get the filename without the path.

Comment: `Dir(strFileToOpen)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract file name from path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743328/how-to-extract-file-name-from-path)

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim arr, strFileToOpen 

strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFileName(Title:="Select File to Open")
arr = Split(strFileToOpen, Application.PathSeparator)
debug.print arr(ubound(arr)) '>> filename
```

or (if on Windows)

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Debug.Print fso.GetFileName(strFileToOpen)
```

`FileSystemObject` has a bunch of methods for working with paths.

Answer (score 2):

InstrRev(strFileToOpen,"\") will return the position of the last "\". Add one to get the position of the first character of the filename.extension portion.

```
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFileName(Title:="Select File to Open")
If Len(strFileToOpen) Then
    strFileToOpen = Mid$(strFileToOpen, InstrRev(strFileToOpen,"\")+1)
End If
```