# Load CSV file in a specific cell using Excel

Tags: excel, import, vba

I currently have a CSV containing some data that needs to be imported every day on an XML Excel template. The template contains header text from cell row A:1 up to A:5.

How can I import the data starting from a specific cell? For example, cell **B:6** onwards.

Comment: @ScottCraner; I don't think this is a duplicate of the hyperlinked question, Angel is asking to import the data into a template worksheet at cell B6, not put the name of the file in a cell.

Comment: @GMalc You are right. All I would like to do is insert the csv data starting from cell B6 onwards and try to get it automized. I'm using this as reference but it's giving me an error compiling using the vba scripting feature in excel. [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46474018/vba-place-uploaded-csv-file-name-into-cell-on-certain-sheet)

Comment: I can't provide you an answer, won't let me, but i can provide some basic code here...
`Workbooks.Open Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NameOf.csv"
Workbooks("NameOf.csv").Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(6, 2)

ActiveWorkbook.Close`

Your .cvs file needs to be save in the same folder as your macro enabled file.