# How do I make a macro that enables me to import data from one workbook to another ?B

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I would like to import data by clicking on a button assigned with the macro which would open the file browser, prompting the user to open the excel file they would like to import. I have tried to debug my codes but my For Each loop keeps getting an error, any help is appreciated!

```
Sub BrowseForFile()  
    Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer

    fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse for Workbook")
    Workbooks.Open (fileName)

    For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
        total = Workbooks("FIEP.xlsm").Worksheets.count
        Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
          after:=Workbooks("FIEP.xlsm").Worksheets(total)
    Next sheet

    Workbooks(fileName).Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Please detail the error

Comment: It states Subscript out of range and highlights "For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets"

Comment: It doesn't like the path part of the now open workbook. It expects just the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable for the workbook object:

```
Sub BrowseForFile()

 Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Long
 Dim wb As Workbook

 fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse for Workbook")


 Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName)

 For Each sheet In wb.Worksheets
    total = Workbooks("FIEP.xlsm").Worksheets.count
    sheet.Copy after:=Workbooks("FIEP.xlsm").Worksheets(total)
 Next sheet

 wb.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the file path part. Variety of methods available. I used the one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743328/how-to-extract-file-name-from-path).

> The [Workbooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841074(v=office.14).aspx) object is the collection of all the Workbook
>   objects that are currently open in the Microsoft Excel application.

It does not need the file path just the name. You could also have said `ActiveWorkbook`, though this would have been perhaps less robust.

Edit: Or as in @TimWilliam's answer, you can store the now open workbook in a variable and use that as the reference.

```
Option Explicit

Sub BrowseForFile()

    Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer

    fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse for Workbook")

    Workbooks.Open (fileName)

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject 'Requires references to MS Scripting Runtime

    fileName = fso.GetFileName(fileName)

    For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets '
        Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
        after:=Workbooks("FIEP.xlsm").Worksheets(total)
    Next sheet

    Workbooks(fileName).Close

End Sub
```