# How to extract the filename of a full path in Excel worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I need to extract the filenames of column B for example extract `pm5a1tktzlrzzgno2r5l.png` from `v1448360146/pm5a1tktzlrzzgno2r5l.png` and compare that result to the value in column A.

[image: image shown here]

Comment: Your question is unclear.  If you expect others to spend their time trying to help you, then you should spend 5-10 minutes formatting your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract file name from path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743328/how-to-extract-file-name-from-path)

Answer (score 1):

Split off the filename and extension then find a match in column A.

```
sub huh()

    dim m as variant, str as string, i as long

    with worksheets("sheet1")
        for i = 1 to .cells(.rows.count, "B").ens(xlup).row
            str = split(.cells(i, "B").value2, chr(47))(ubound(split(.cells(i, "B").value2, chr(47))))
            m = application.match(str, .range("A:A"), 0)
            if not iserror(m) then
                'm is the row number in column A of the matching filename
                debug.print .cells(m, "A").value
                'do something with it
            end if
        next i
    end with

end sub
```

Comment: Hint: OP is using simple slash delimiters for url, too - `chr(47)`

Comment: Thanks for catching that @T.M.

Answer (score 1):

Change Sheet Name, Set the right range and try:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Lr As Long
Dim Position As Long
Dim str As String
Dim i As Long

With Sheets("Sheet1") '<= Change SheetName if needed
    Lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To Lr
        Position = InStrRev(.Cells(i, "B").Value, "/") + 1
        str = Mid(.Cells(i, "B").Value, Position, ((Len(.Cells(i, "B").Value)) - (Position - 1)))
        If str = .Cells(i, "A").Value Then
            MsgBox "Same!"
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Jeeped thanks for you guidelines.i have edit the code!

Answer (score 1):

Open your Excel file, press Alt+F10 (or start your VBEditor from panel), and there create a new module (Insert > new Module). Into a new module put this code:

```
Sub extractFileNames()
Dim rng As Range

'Set your own input range with A and B columns and worksheet name here.
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Your_worksheet_name").Range("A1:B1000")

Dim arr As Variant
arr = rng.Value2  

For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    Dim tmp() As String
    tmp = Split(arr(i, 2), "/")
    arr(i, 1) = tmp(UBound(tmp))      
Next i
rng.Value2 = arr 
End Sub
```

You can run this macro with any supported way you want [(see the link, if you don't know how)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/run-a-macro-5e855fd2-02d1-45f5-90a3-50e645fe3155).

Also, if you don't want to use macros in your file, you may try to use functions like **=RIGHT($B2,LEN($B2) - FIND("/", $B2))** , but that won't be helpful if you have too many paths or they have different number of delimeters.

Comment: When an array is taken from a range like this, it's 1-based by default. And when array is created in VBA it's 0-based by default. But to avoid Option Base problems, it's better to use LBound() and UBound() functions in such case.

Comment: My bad! Of course, it is a one-based 2-D array. I guess UBound(arr) instead of UBound(arr, 1) had me thinking of something else.

Comment: UBound(arr) and UBound(arr, 1) are the same for 2D-array, because dimension number is optional and 1 by default.