# Reference a Workbook with a String Variable

Tags: excel, vba, string

I am trying to create a block of code that allows one to receive the name of an unknown workbook, and reference data from it.  Referencing by index number doesn’t seem like a viable option as users will often have other workbooks out at the same time.  The unknown workbook is already open, but I need to retrieve its name. I am using a FileDialog to allow the user to select the desired workbook, save the filepath as a string, then use it to reference the workbook.

When I attempt to reference the workbook, I get a Subscript Out of Range error.  Directly inputting the name of the workbook instead of a variable worked just fine, but attempting to use a variable didn’t work.  I tried using quotes, no quotes, and double quotes, but the error remained the same.

Here is my code.  What exactly was I doing wrong?

```
Sub ObtainExternalWorkbook()

'Declare variables
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim WK As FileDialog
    Set WK = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'Acquire file name.
  MsgBox ("Please select the desired file to be used.")
        With WK
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .Title = "Select the desired file."
            If .Show = False Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        filepath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        End With


'Use file name to activate workbook.
    Workbooks(" & filepath & ").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to open it before you can activate it.

Comment: @braX: Op said "the unknown workbook is already open", so while it might be useful to add some code to check that it actually is open (and an Excel-file). I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you say the workbook is already open, this has to be the case to activate, the problem is your variable `filepath`. this returns the full path and name. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743328/how-to-extract-file-name-from-path) gives you a function to extract only the filename and extension.

Try filling a `filename` variable via that function after a file has been chosen and then `Workbooks(filename).Activate` should work.